# Which book is the Black Blade feature for the SwordMage in?

Tags: dnd-4e, pathfinder-1e, product-identification, swordmage

I remember reading something about a 'black blade' class feature for the swordmage but now I can't find it. It was basically where the 'black blade' was an intelligent weapon with it's own agenda. I was thinking of using it for the game tonight, but I can't find the information on it, and the GM won't let me play it without a source, not that I blame him, not much to go on with what I remember.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about this feature? Since looking on the compendium I can't find anything that fits this description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't thinking of the Black Blade from the [Blade Bound Archetype for the Magus in Pathfinder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/bladebound)? It's detailed as exactly what you put here.

Comment: That's exactly what I was remembering. I just had my games mixed up apparently,.  Thank you for helping me.